# R: Copying files over to a remote server

Tags: r, rcurl

I have two remote servers that I can access from my machine using passwordless SSH. Can I copy over files to those servers using an R package/function? I found [`RCurl::scp`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rcurl/docs/scp) but that says it can only copy files *from* a remote server. What would I have to do to perform the transaction to transfer files *to* a remote server?

Comment: Your SSH client should have a command for transferring files.  For example, PuTTY has the pscp.exe command for transferring files through the SSH tunnel.  Could you use `system` to write a call to pscp.exe?

Comment: @Benjamin Yeah, that is what I ended up doing, but was hoping for an R wrapper around this. Perhaps I will write one.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use scp method by giving the private key file of your target server

```
scp -i /path/to/privatekey/of/target/remoteserver -rp /home/path to/file/* username@192.168.0.210:/path/to/folder
```